# Change Activity After Connected to Bluetooth Device

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth, chat

I want to change activity as soon as I get connected to A device on Bluetooth,While getting the data continuously from Bluetooth.
Link- https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat

Answer (score 0):

There's not such thing as "change" activity.

To open an Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

To close an Activity:

```
finish();
```

If you want to make Activity look like a change rather than an open/close, you'll need to remove open/close animations in your `styles.xml` file:

```
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
```

Comment: I do know how to "start" another activity, this activity should start after connected to Bluetooth

Comment: Simply use the code when Bluetooth is connected to device, the sample BluetoothChat will help you to detect how to detect if device is connected and then start the activity.